# How to extract a line of text that moves within a text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to remove a link from a webpage which changes daily I have managed to get to the point of been left with a line of text that the link is in but I cant get it as it is surrounded by characters that keep messing with my attempts, I am not very good at it and have been basically butchering other scripts to attempt to work it out, now in hour 12 I have admitted defeat and need help
 the point i am at is having the following in a text file

```
    </a><p>Support the free distribution of this forecast by visiting our sponsors website.<p><b>Select forecast - </b><a href="?fdate=140403">Tomorrow</a> / <a href="?fdate=140404">Friday</a> / <a href="?fdate=140405">Saturday</a><p><hr><h5>Viewing forecast for Thursday, 3rd April, 2014</h5><p>Forecast last reviewed on Wednesday, 02/04/14 at 16:17<p><a href="jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF" target="blank" border="0"><img src="images/pdf.gif" align="left"></a><br><a href="jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF" target="blank">Click here to access the PDF version of the forecast</a>.<br><br><br><br><hr><h5>Summary for all mountain areas</h5><p>Low cloud will remain widespread across eastern mountains south to about the central or southern Pennines. Higher summits may well be above the cloud. Outbreaks of rain will move north, locally heavy. Local gusty winds.<p><hr><h5>Headline, Cairngorms National Park, Monadhliath</h5><p>Outbreaks of rain; hazy. Locally gusty wind.<p><p><hr><h5>How Windy?</h5><p>East or southeasterly, 20 to occasionally 30 or 35mph.<p><h5>Effect Of Wind?</h5><p>Will impede ease of walking on some areas, not necessarily the highest areas. Sudden gusts west of major ridges and some passes and cols.<p><hr><h5>How Wet?</h5><p>Bursts of rain<p>Rain now and again, ranging from brief light showers to heavier bursts lasting an hour or two - these most likely west of the A9.<p><hr><h5>Cloud on the hills?</h5><p>Widespread east<p>Most, perhaps all higher areas intermittently cloud free. But very low cloud over North Sea will shroud areas accessible from Deeside from lower slopes, although higher tops (above about 900m) often above the cloud.<p><h5>Chance of cloud free Munros?</h5><p>80%<p><h5>Sunshine and air clarity?</h5><p>Patchy weak sunshine. Very hazy low level, but excellent visibility many higher slopes. Extensive fog eastern mountains, particularly lower slopes.<p><hr><h5>How Cold? (at 900m)</h5><p>4 to 6C, but 2C where in cloud.<p><h5>Freezing level</h5><p>Above the summits<p><hr><h5>Planning Outlook for all mountain areas from Friday, 4th April, 2014</h5><p>Winds will turn south to southwesterly into the weekend as rain bearing fronts come in off the Atlantic. Snowmelt in Scotland will continue. Winds at times approaching or reaching gale higher areas.
```

the output i am wanting is : jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF

I have managed to work it out the rest of my problem but as the address changes in length aswell each day i havn't managed to work out how to do it

if it can be in bat or intiated from BAT that would be great or the output to a text file so I can continue to process it in BAT.

hopefully someone can help

Cheers

Sam

Comment: You just forgot to explain _how_ the line can me located! Is _not_ the only line with `<a href=`, and there are _two lines_ with "jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF". So? Is the line with `target="blank"`?

Comment: @Aacini The code was helpfully edited but artificial codebreaks were entered.  The original post has it all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

The name of the text file : `input.txt`
The output is putted in : `output.txt`

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('type input.txt') do (
set ligne=%%a
set ligne=!ligne:^<p^>^<a href^== #1# !
set ligne=!ligne: target= #2# !
)

set sw1=0

for %%b in (!ligne!') do (
if "%%b"=="#2#" goto:end
if !sw1!==1 echo %%b>Output.txt
if "%%b"=="#1#" set sw1=1
)
goto:eof

:end
type output.txt
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: The code was helpfully edited but artificial codebreaks were entered.  The original post has it all on one line.

Comment: I didn't examine your code.  I merely told you that the source format has changed,

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you have *not* specified the rules to find the target line/string, so we can only guess... The Batch file below find the first line that have both "href" and "target" strings and extract the second token enclosed in quotes:

```
@echo off

for /F ^tokens^=2^delims^=^" %%a in ('findstr "href" input.txt ^| findstr "target"') do echo %%a& goto continue
:continue
```

Output:

```
jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF
```

If this method does not solve your problem, specify the rules please...

Comment: when I test your code the output is : `?fdate=140403`

Comment: @sachadee: Oops! I used [the data](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22821879/revisions) _badly edited_ by [IarsAnders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3258572/larsanders)... `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

The single line you pasted in your question can be parsed as follows by REPL.BAT

What it does is look for a period `\.` that is 4 characters before a double quote `\q` and it gives you the text from the double quote before that until the double quote that was matched.  It returns `"jnzolmdtgobavkjz/EH.PDF"` and if you want it without double quotes then that can also be done.

repl: This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt"| repl ".*(\q.*\....\q).*" "$1" x >newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22821879.txt) DO SET "line=%%a"
:loop
SET "line=!line:*<p>=!"
IF NOT "%line:~0,8%"=="<a href=" GOTO loop
FOR /f "delims=<>" %%a IN ("%line%") DO FOR %%z IN (%%a) DO IF NOT "%%z"=="%%~z" SET "line=%%~z"&GOTO done
:done
ECHO %line%
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22821879.txt` containing your data for my testing.